# Advance COALESCE

Tags: sql, transformation

may someone please help me on this, if possible. i have data as given below:

```
ID|Dia|Wid|BM1|BM2 |BM3 |BO|OFF|SEAT|NUT |R1|R2|R3|R4|R5|R6|R7 |R8 |R9 |
154|17|8.5|120|NULL|NULL|8 |54| Con |Acor|  |  |  |  |  |BO|   |   |   |
156|18|9.5|120|NULL|NULL|8 |5 | Deg |ZOOM|  |  |  |  |  |BO|OFF|   |NUT|    
179|19|10 |120|NULL|NULL|8 |79| STAR|Acor|  |  |  |  |  |BO|   |SEA|   |
```

and i want to display data like this:

```
ID|Dia|Wid|BM1|BM2 |BM3 |BO|OFF|SEAT|NUT  |R1|R2 |R3 |R4|R5|R6|R7 |R8|R9|
154|17|8.5|120|NULL|NULL|8 |54 |Con |Acor |BO|   |   |  |  |  |   |  |  |   
156|18|9.5|120|NULL|NULL|8 |5  |Deg |ZOOM |BO|OFF|NUT|  |  |  |   |  |  |
179|19|10 |120|NULL|NULL|8 |79 |STAR|Acor |BO|SEA|   |  |  |  |   |  |  |
```

All values from Rn fields should be moved to the left leaving no blanks between the fields with values. For example column r2 will only have value when col r1 is filled, similarly column r3 can be filled only when r1 and r2 filled.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.  Can you clarify the problem?

Comment: If r1 is filled then r2 can be null ?

Comment: Hello,
i am using some conditional check query on a column, and if data in a column is not satisfy
the condition then it appear in column (r1 to r9).
r1 to r9 hold data if any incorrect data from DIA to NUT
but my problem is business user want to see data in a non blank fashion.
like if any invalid data in two column of a row, then appear in R1 and R2

Comment: if any one column have wrong data then R1 get filled, and remaining all null
when two column of same row have wrong data then R1 and R2 filled, remaining all null
when three have wrong data then R1 and R2 and r3 filled, remaining all null

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea for SQL server

```
;WITH ordered AS
(
    SELECT t.ID, o.Ordering, o.Value FROM table t
    OUTER APPLY 
    (
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS Ordering, 
            Value 
        FROM 
            (VALUES
                (1, R1), (2, R2), (3, R3), (4, R4), (5, R5), (6, R6), (7, R7), (8, R8), (9, R9)
            ) data(Id, Value) 
        WHERE NULLIF(Value, '') IS NOT NULL
    ) AS o
)
SELECT 
    *, 
    (SELECT Value FROM ordered WHERE ID = t.ID AND Ordering = 1) AS R1,
    (SELECT Value FROM ordered WHERE ID = t.ID AND Ordering = 2) AS R2,
    (SELECT Value FROM ordered WHERE ID = t.ID AND Ordering = 3) AS R3,
    (SELECT Value FROM ordered WHERE ID = t.ID AND Ordering = 4) AS R4,
    (SELECT Value FROM ordered WHERE ID = t.ID AND Ordering = 5) AS R5,
    (SELECT Value FROM ordered WHERE ID = t.ID AND Ordering = 6) AS R6,
    (SELECT Value FROM ordered WHERE ID = t.ID AND Ordering = 7) AS R7,
    (SELECT Value FROM ordered WHERE ID = t.ID AND Ordering = 8) AS R8,
    (SELECT Value FROM ordered WHERE ID = t.ID AND Ordering = 9) AS R9
FROM table t
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/2957)

Comment: Thanks Eric. do i need to replace Value with column name, Please suggest

Comment: @RajeeKasthuri You don't need to rename the columns of `ordered` table. Replace the table name of your actual table and edit the columns to be select is ok

Comment: i am getting error like Incorrect syntax near ','., only replaced table name.

Comment: just replaced id with actual column name product_id and table name but getting error 
Incorrect syntax near ','. kindly suggest

Comment: @RajeeKasthuri Opps, the `VALUE` should be `VALUES`, see edit